# Guessing a radical expression from a decimal expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a function in Maple or Mathematica that takes a truncated decimal expansion, and will try to guess at the value in terms of radicals? Can I use the gfun package in Maple for this? Thanks for any help or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a function in Maple or Mathematica that takes a truncated decimal expansion, and will try to guess at the value in terms of radicals?

The old versions of *Mathematica* had `Recognize.m` (but this generates the minimal polynomial instead of the algebraic number itself), while newer versions now have the `RootApproximant[]` function. This can be used in conjunction with `ToRadicals[]`.

As a neat example, here's where I use `RootApproximant[]` to guess at an algebraic representation of a special value of the [modular lambda function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html):

```
RootApproximant[N[ModularLambda[I Sqrt[5]]]]
Root[1 - 72*#1 + 88*#1^2 - 32*#1^3 + 16*#1^4 & , 1, 0]

FullSimplify /@ Apart[ToRadicals[%]]
1/2 - Sqrt[-2 + Sqrt[5]]
```

which matches the results of formula 15 in the MathWorld link, while

```
RootApproximant[N[ModularLambda[I Sqrt[1/2]]]]
-2 + 2*Sqrt[2]
```

matches formula 35.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it can be done, though not quite in the way you ask. Get very high precision accuracy for some number $x,$ then make a vector (list) out of $1,x,x^2, x^3, \ldots, x^n$ for some not large $n.$ You may then ask for an integer relation among these $(n+1)$ numbers, which gives you the coefficients of a polynomial for which $x$ is a root. In case you chose $n$ too large, ask to factor the polynomial over the integers, to get the lowest degree polynomial for which $x$ is a root. From that information you may, with some creativity, calculate an expression for $x$ in terms of radicals. This final step will only give satisfactory results in very special circumstances.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSLQ_algorithm#Applications

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerRelation.html